# Letter spacing in different browsers

Tags: css, browser, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font and line spacing in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836735/font-and-line-spacing-in-different-browsers)

I have to create a pixel-perfect html from a given design. It uses a custom font.
I am checking it in Firefox and Chrome and see that in Chrome spacing between letter is larger than in Firefox. Though I need them to look identically. I tried to set letter-spacing to 0 and it didn't help. How can I workaround? What if I use Cufon (don't want to use it though)?

[image]

Comment: Hi Sergey. Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836735/font-and-line-spacing-in-different-browsers ?

Comment: This may depend on the font. It is possible that the font has kerning information in a format that cannot be used by all browsers. This sounds far-fetched, but in the absence of specific information (like the URL of a demo page), it’s really guesswork.

Comment: That question only answers line high etc, not letter spacing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're never going to get pixel-perfect across every browser and platform. Even if the letter-spacing is the same (which is seems to be if you set it to 0), the slight differences in anti-aliasing can make the letters appear wider. There's nothing in the CSS spec that specifies how browser render those small details.

Workarounds would be Cufon (yech) and images (yech). Pixel-perfect and the web are simply not good friends.