# How to show exact distance in PSD file to CSS?

Tags: html, css, photoshop, psd

I'm a newbie of converting PSD to HTML, CSS. I met the problem that make me tired several days, it is about aligning elements in photoshop file to CSS. Here is a list in psd file that I want take it to HTML, CSS form :

[image]

I use Ruler tool and get distance between list is 13px and font size is 12px.

Here is my code to create this list in HTML :

HTML :

```
<div id="categories">
  <ul id="list-cate">
    <li><a href="#">DRESSES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TOPS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HANDBAGS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINGERIE</a></li>
  </ul> </div>
```

CSS :

```
#categories {
    width: 225px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

#list-cate {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#list-cate li {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
```

But when I run it in Firefox, use Measure plugin, I saw it display :

[image]

I don't know why it is wrong distance between PSD and CSS. Anyone can give me an answer for that, thanks !!

Comment: `line-height`? Your font-size may be 12px, but the line-height will usually be greater than that.

Comment: Ah yes. I use Bootstrap framework. Are you guide me the config for this ?

Comment: You can get answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836735/font-and-line-spacing-in-different-browsers

Comment: Thank but it not successfull :(

Answer (score 0):

In the css of #list-cate add margin:0;

`#list-cate { margin:0;}`

Comment: Thank but it not successful :(